# Php , laravel, socket -Horizontal scaling technique

Tags: php, sockets, laravel, redis, ratchet

I have a laravel app, and in it I am using php ratchet library to have persistent connection between client and the user for real time communication(for now it is just one way, i.e. , only the server can send a message to client).

With this architecture , how can I have multiple of these laravel servers , each having their own set of clients connected to them , to inter communicate?

I am thinking about using REDIS , and having a redis server , which all my nodes will connect to (using pub sub).

My service is similar to a group messaging app (one user has many groups , and one group has many users ), and so far (right now I have a single server and no redis) , I get all the user's groups , and subscribe him to those topics (with topic name something like GROUP_ 1,GROUP_ 8 ,GROUP_ 99 etc).

I would like to know how each node can subscribe to specific topics in redis (it would not make sense to send ALL redis messages to ALL my nodes ).

Laravel's Example says to use a php artisan command like so:

```
class RedisSubscribe extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'redis:subscribe';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Subscribe to a Redis channel';

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Redis::subscribe(['test-channel'], function($message) {
            echo $message;
        });
    }
}
```

But , I want to be able to subscribe , unsubscribe from certain topics at runtime(after the artisan command was run). How can I do that in laravel ?

Comment: 1. Would it make sense for each topic to be a different channel? If so, that's your answer. 2. What's the problem with subscribing/unsubscribing at runtime? I don't know Laravel, so I might be missing the correct answer for that paradigm. (the `Command` classes). However, just calling `Redis::subscribe(['test-channel'], function($message) { });` and `Redis::unsubscribe(['test-channel'], function($message) { });` should be enough, no?

Comment: thing is, when you run the command, the php script runs forever . once i start it, how will I modify the channels ?

Comment: You could subscribe to several channels, including a 'client-control' channel or even 'client-3-control' channel. When you get a 'subscribe' or 'unsubscribe' message from that channel, you perform that action. When you get a 'stop' message, you know to call Redis::unsubscribe for all the channels you're subscribed to and to kill the command (return). Obviously you'll need some sort of state stored somewhere, maybe even in Redis itself, to allow an external controller to cause these subscriptions/unsubscriptions/stop

Answer (score 3):

1. So if I totally understand your question, you are looking for a way to send messages to users that are connected on multiple WebsocketServers.
2. And you want no overhead by sending it to websocketservers that have no clients whom are subscribed to the receiving topic/channel.

---

**Part 1 answer:**

I currently also do this on about 50 different websocketServers so this is a functional design.
I have all 50 of the websocketservers their IP addresses stored in my database.
And I also attached a limit of 8096 users to each of the websocketservers.

**Pub/Sub part**

For each user that wants to connect I first call The API to determine which websocket a user has to connect to. This is set up so that one server doesn't have 8k users and others are empty. Another way of achieving this is by using loadbalancing and hooking up all different websocketservers behind the loadbalancer.

Once this is done I always save to which websocketserver a user is connected in my database. If a user also subscribes to channels a new entry is added in the database.

When a user unsubscribes from a certain topic/channel the user's entry for that channel is removed from the database.

**Sending messages**

To send a message to the different users I am currently using an API as well since I do only use the websocket from the server to the client, not the other way around.

On a user sends a message to someone else the API call will also notice the pushserver I have running. The pushserver is also conencted to the database.

For every message the pushserver receives it gets which users are subscribed to that channel/topic at that moment in time.

It then will only send the data to the websockets whom have connections/users that are subscribed to this channel/topic that you are addressing.

---

**Part 2 answer**

It is kind of in the previous answer already but the point of it is to only send data to the websockets that have listening clients. This information is gotten from the database.

Database like scheme that I currently have for this problem(only important parts of it are included.

template:
table(column1, column2);

- User(userId);
- Websocket(websocketId, IP-address, userLimit);
- Connections(connectionId, user.userId, websocket.websocketId);
- Subscriptions(connection.connectionId, channelId);

If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Thabks for the answer.Instead of using an SQL database like yours,i wanted to use redis cache. And I would like to know how to sub/unsub from a particular redis topic from inside  messageComponentInterface

Comment: I have never used the redis cache and am looking into it now because of tyour post I'll get back to you if I find an answer. 
The setup above should although give a reference for future devs that don't really have an idea on how to expand their websocket servers.

Comment: Are you planning to use redis.io or anything else

Comment: Redis.io using elasticache